# NLog: logging an object serialized to JSON

Tags: .net, json, nlog

I have .Net project with NLog configuration which allows me to produce JSON-formatted log file. It works fine with simple text messages. Now, I need to log a number of arbitrary objects already serialized to JSON. When I log those JSON strings as log messages, NLog puts the text in quotes and subsequently escapes inner JSON syntax. This renders such output unusable. So far I have failed to find an NLog feature or layout setting that would simply dump my JSON string as a literal, without quotation marks and escape characters. Am I missing something?

Example. Currently my log entries look like:]

```
{ "dateTime": "2017-06-07 11:50:55.7324", "level": "DEBUG", "message": "\"description\": \"blah-blah\", \"Request\": { \"Request URL\":\/somepagepage\/}, \"Content\": { \"Form\": { ... } , \"Body\": \"Blah\" } ", "utcDateTime": "2017-06-05 06:10:34.1411" }
```

Instead, I need to make them to look like:

```
{ "dateTime": "2017-06-07 11:50:55.7324", "level": "DEBUG", "message":
 { "description": "blah-blah", "Request": { "Request URL":/somepagepage/, "Content": { "Form": {...}, "Body": "Blah" }  }, "utcDateTime": "2017-06-05 06:10:34.1411" }
```

Relevant section from NLog.config:

```xml
 <layout xsi:type="JsonLayout">
   <attribute name="dateTime" layout="${longdate}" />
   <attribute name="level" layout="${level:upperCase=true}"/>
   <attribute name="message" layout="${message}" /> 
   <attribute name="utcDateTime" layout="${longdate:universalTime=true}" />
 </layout>
```

Ultimately, I would like to see a log entry with JSON nested inside "message", and not a quoted version of it.

Comment: what's your config?

Comment: What happens if you add the parameter encode="false" to the message-element? (attribute name="mesage" encode="false" ...)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you @RolfKristensen -  this did the trick! Although plain text message now comes out with no quotes, but I can make write a custom layout rendered to handle this. You deserve the green tick.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per @Rolf Kristensen's commentary above. Essentially, parameter encode="false" allows to log unquoted JSON:

```
  <attribute name="message" layout="${message}" encode="false" />
```

Plain text also comes out unquoted now, but this can be dealt with by a custom layout renderer that can tell plain text from JSON.

Comment: Do you have an example of the custom layout render that can tell plain text from JSON?

Answer (score 3):

Another way you can add json to your logging is to use the JsonLayout layout type and set includeAllProperties to true.

Your logger layout config should look like this:

```
<layout xsi:type="JsonLayout" includeAllProperties="true" maxRecursionLimit="4">
</layout>
```

And your logging code something like this:

```
ILogger Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
MyClass request = new MyClass(){ThisProp = "foo", ThatProp = "bar"};

LogEventInfo e = new LogEventInfo(LogLevel.Info, "EmptyResponseLogger", "");
e.Properties["Request"] = request;

Logger.Log(e);
```

And you should end up with something like:

```
{ "time": "2019-02-05 19:12:10.1643", "logger": "MyClassLogger", "level": "INFO", "Request": {"ThisProp":"foo", "ThatProp": "bar"} }
```

Doing this will write out a JSON object on the 'Request' property of the log line and give you the response you are looking for. The maxRecursionLimit sets how far down the object tree

[Json Layout Documentation](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/JsonLayout)

Comment: I think you misunderstand. The OP is starting with a JSON string representing some (potentially unknown) class. I'm dealing with the same thing - I get a payload from another service and want to simply log it without all the NLog escaping characters to the JSON string.